# How to check the ios version of the app in react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to check what the app would look like in ios and I can't use xcode since I'm on windows and the open web using npm start only shows the android version.

Comment: Go to `ios` folder and then go to` Podfile`. At the top, find `ios` version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info#getversion

Examples

npm install --save react-native-device-info

```
   import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

   let readableVersion = DeviceInfo.getReadableVersion();

   // iOS: 1.0.1.32
   // Android: 1.0.1.234 
   // Windows: ?
```